# When to use sapply and when to use R's internal vectorization?

Tags: r, vectorization

Consider this code:

```
strings<-c("string_x", "strxng_y", "xstring_z")
replace_letters <- function(string){
    gsub("x", "a", string)
}
replace_letters(strings)
```

which returns:

```
[1] "string_a"  "strang_y"  "astring_z"
```

but also:

```
sapply(strings, replace_letters)
```

which returns:

```
   string_x    strxng_y   xstring_z 
  "string_a"  "strang_y" "astring_z"
```

This would imply that `sapply` and related functions are not necessary, because R has internal vectorization. This however, seems to not be the case. When and why is R's internal vectorization insufficient and `sapply` and related functions necessary?

Comment: `gsub` happens to be vectorized over its first argument (`strings` in your example), so in this case `sapply` is unnecessary. There are certainly plenty of legitimate uses for `sapply` though, one of which being when you need to apply a non-vectorized function to a vector.

Comment: Also, if you want to apply a function to more than one column of a data frame, or if you want to apply a function to every element of a list.

Comment: for example, the `pattern` argument of `gsub` is not vectorized, so if you wanted to replace with changing patterns, you would have to loop in some way.

Comment: They are necessary when the function in question isn't already vectorized.

Comment: In this case I'd choose `vapply()` over `sapply()` because you know that the result is always a length-one character vector